# displaying 2 private messages to same destination with SQL

Tags: php, sql, message

So i'm trying to implement a Private messaging system and so i use this code to extract the info from an SQL table:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pm` WHERE `to` = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}'");
$pm = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

and essentially all this code does is pulls values from columns

```
(INT) from, (INT) to, (VARCHAR) subject and (VARCHAR) message
```

and it all worked until i sent more then 1 message to the same user.
thise code only shows the first message, and i have no idea how to make it show all the messages, so any help would be appriciated.

***EDIT*** 
Forgot to mention that the table itself is named 'pm'
***EDIT2***
this is how i echo the output:

```
<h3>From: </h3><?php echo $pm['from']; ?>
<h3>Subject: </h3> <?php echo $pm['subject']; ?>
<h3>Message: </h3> <?php echo $pm['message']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really tell us how you were echoing out the PM's.  But here's how you would print every one.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['message'];
}
```

Comment: This is how i ecoh them
`<h3>From: </h3><?php echo $pm['from']; ?>
<h3>Subject: </h3> <?php echo $pm['subject']; ?>
<h3>Message: </h3> <?php echo $pm['message']; ?>`

Comment: @JordanJones Could you put the exact code you used in the OP?

Comment: there, i posted the code i use to echo the private messages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient but you can add a `time_created` column and a `was_sent` column.  Have your query grab the oldest unsent message and then mark it as sent.  Repeat.

Comment: The op is looking for all messages, this is a method to obtain just one message, but determine which one.

Comment: Whoops, misread.  In that case go with @julienhaversano's answer.